# Largest amount of entries in lua table

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am trying to build a [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) in Lua and i tried several things but i see myself confronted with the following problem:
The tables of Lua are to small for this scenario. If I just want to create a table with all numbers (see example below), the table is too  "small" even with only 1/8 (...) of the number (the number is pretty big I admit)...

```
max = 600851475143
numbers = {}

for i=1, max do
    table.insert(numbers, i)
end
```

If I execute this script on my Windows machine there is an error message saying: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua.exe: not enough memory`. With Lua 5.3 running on my Linux machine I tried that too, error was just `killed`. So it is pretty obvious that lua can´t handle the amount of entries.

I don´t really know whether it is just impossible to store that amount of entries in a lua table or there is a simple solution for this (tried it by using a long string aswell...)? And what exactly is the largest amount of entries in a Lua table?

**Update:** And would it be possible to manually allocate somehow more memory for the table?

**Update 2 (Solution for second question):** The second question is an easy one, I just tested it by running every number until the program breaks: **33.554.432** (2^25) entries fit in one one-dimensional table on my 12 GB RAM system. Why 2^25? Because 64 Bit per number * 2^25 = 2147483648 Bits which are exactly 2 GB. This seems to be the standard memory allocation size for the Lua for Windows 32 Bit compiler.

> P.S. You may have noticed that this number is from the Euler Project Problem 3. Yes I am trying to accomplish that. Please don´t give specific hints (..). Thank you :)

Comment: Long array consisting of `N` Lua values (even booleans) takes at least `16*N` bytes of memory in Lua.

Comment: Like I explained in my answer and @Piglet in his, there are most likely ``` 64*N``` Bits (:8 --> 16 bytes) of memory occupied. The question is how to solve the problem...

Comment: Both of you are wrong.  Lua spends 16 bytes for one element of an array (128 bits).  Lua is so wasteful :-)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Can you tell me how to do this more efficiently or how to manually allocate the memory for the table?

Comment: You should find another solution (with shorter tables). And you asked to not give you hints :-)

Comment: Ok, I'll give you *non-specific* hint: this task is not solvable by Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: Thank you, i figured a few minutes ago that I would need to solve it another way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sieve of Eratosthenes only requires one bit per number, representing whether the number has been marked non-prime or not.

One way to reduce memory usage would be to use bitwise math to represent multiple bits in each table entry.  Current Lua implementations have intrinsic support for bitwise-or, -and etc.  Depending on the underlying implementation, you should be able to represent 32 or 64 bits (number flags) per table entry.

Another option would be to use one or more very long strings instead of a table.  You only need a linear array, which is really what a string is.  Just have a long string with "t" or "f", or "0" or "1", at every position.

Caveat: String manipulation in Lua always involves duplication, which rapidly turns into n² or worse complexity in terms of performance.  You wouldn't want one continuous string for the whole massive sequence, but you could probably break it up into blocks of a thousand, or of some power of 2.  That would reduce your memory usage to 1 byte per number while minimizing the overhead.

**Edit:** After noticing a point made elsewhere, I realized your maximum number is so large that, even with a bit per number, your memory requirements would optimally be about **73 gigabytes**, which is extremely impractical.  I would recommend following the advice Piglet gave in their answer, to look at Jon Sorenson's version of the sieve, which works on segments of the space instead of the whole thing.

I'll leave my suggestion, as it still might be useful for Sorenson's sieve, but yeah, you have a bigger problem than you realize.

Comment: Thanks again, i will try to adjust my algorithm accordingly the next days. I will see how I am going to implement this whole thing :)

Answer (score 1):

Lua uses double precision floats to represent numbers. That's 64bits per number.
600851475143 numbers result in almost 4.5 Terabytes of memory.

So it's not Lua's or its tables' fault. The error message even says

> not enough memory

You just don't have enough RAM to allocate that much.

If you would have read the linked Wikipedia article carefully you would have found the following section:

> As Sorenson notes, the **problem with the sieve of Eratosthenes is** not
>   the number of operations it performs but rather its **memory**
>   **requirements**.[8] **For large n, the range of primes may not fit in**
>   **memory**; worse, even for moderate n, its cache use is highly
>   suboptimal. The algorithm walks through the entire array A, exhibiting
>   almost no locality of reference.
>
> **A solution to these problems is offered by segmented sieves**, where
>   only portions of the range are sieved at a time.[9] These have been
>   known since the 1970s, and work as follows
>   ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read that article (that is basically why I tried to split the number in 8 pieces). :) I have 16 GB of RAM, so that shouln´t be a problem. But as I described in my answer: Lua only uses 2 of them...

Comment: @creyD - It sounds like you're using a 32-bit implementation of Lua.  Can you switch to a 64-bit one?  If you're only getting the 2GB of addressable space implicit in a 32-bit app, you can't possibly represent 600,851,475,143 numbers.  That would be, at the bare minimum, 1 bit per number, or 75,106,434,393 bytes... that's 75 gigabytes, about 73 more than you have.  In fact, it's about 9 gigabytes more than even a really good PC has these days.  Are you sure you really want to use that maximum number?  If so, you're going to have to come up with an incremental solution that cleans up backwards.

Comment: @creyD In fact, that's what Piglet, above, is referring to in the second block quote.

Comment: @Piglet - Check your SI prefixes.  A raw array of 600851475143 double-precision numbers would need ~4.5 TiB, not GiB.  :)

Comment: @AikenDrum oh yeah you're right, I was confused by the decimal point on my calculator... I have English windows but somehow my calculator shows results in German notation... thanks for pointing out. Not sure what TiB is though ;) GiB looks aweful enough hehe.

Comment: @Piglet - TiB, GiB, MiB, KiB represent tebibytes, gibibytes, mebibytes, and kibibytes.  They are the correct prefixes to use when you're talking about groupings of 1024 instead of 1000.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte for a jumping-off point.  They should really teach this in computer science these days.

Comment: @AikenDrum I never heard about that. 1 kilobyte is 1024 bytes. that's just something you know :D  at least that's what I thought till today and what I learned  >25 years ago. thanks for bringing me up to date :)

Comment: @Piglet - If it's any consolation, I learned the same, about the same number of years ago, and only learned about the *bi prefixes a couple of years ago.  I must say, it's nice to have a way to differentiate the two, but it does often require explanations, as seen here.  It's worth it, though.

Comment: @AikenDrum and PigletThank you both very much, both of you were of great help. As I am currently working with *Lua for Windows* it is not possible to switch to 64 Bit interpreter, but I will try this on Linux soon. :)

Comment: @creyD on a 32bit system your memory consumtion is just 50% 2.25 TiB is still too much ;)